# Debugging of python script launched from another C++ application in Linux

Tags: python, c++, linux

I have a C++ desktop application in linux and it executes a Python program. I am using execl to run the python program  as below:

```
 execl("python3", "Sample.py",NULL);
```

My query is with respect to debugging this python program. I am adding the following line to enable debugging in the python program:

```
   import pdb; pdb.set_trace();
```

However, I want this python program to be launched in some console/terminal so that I can input the debugging parameters(like c,n etc).

So how can I achieve this using execl function or is there any other method for this? Please suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following method to enable debugging of a python program from my application.

execl("/bin/sh","sh","-c","gnome-terminal -- python Sample.py",(char*)NULL);

However, with the above approach I was not able to wait for the python process to exit/terminate as execl creates gnome-terminal process and that in-turn creates Python process. To overcome that I am looking for a python process like a pslookup after execl and waiting for it to complete.

Please suggest if there are any better ways of doing it.

Thanks.